# duplicate output of more commands

Tags: bash, tee

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="Hello"
VAR2="Bye"

{
echo $VAR1
some stuff here
echo $var2
}
mutt -s "this is a test" destination@gmail.com
```

I need to duplicate (maybe using tee command) the output of code included inside { and } non only by email but also to screen.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="Hello"
var2="Bye"

{
    echo "$var1"
    some stuff here
    echo "$var2"
} | tee >(mutt -s "this is a test" destination@mail.com)
```

- avoid using UPPER CASE variables, they are reserved for system use
- use more quotes

Process Substitution: <(command) or >(command) is replaced by a FIFO or /dev/fd/* entry. Basically shorthand for setting up a named pipe. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution. Example: diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")", "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words